# change image path every x-times

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, loops

How can I repeat the code below, so the image path changes after every two seconds for example

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 userdaten.image FROM userdaten ORDER BY Rnd(ID)", con);

        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read()) { PictureTrainLabel.Text = "~/Image/" + dr["image"].ToString(); }

            PictureTrain.ImageUrl = PictureTrainLabel.Text;


        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: "PictureTrainLabel.Text" - is that a Winforms application?

Comment: No, it runs in browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that code within a timer, that way you can run it every two seconds. I'm not sure how you plan on changing the path, because I'm not sure what you mean, but the logic for that can be done within the OnTimedEvent.

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 userdaten.image FROM userdaten ORDER BY Rnd(ID)", con);

        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read()) { PictureTrainLabel.Text = "~/Image/" + dr["image"].ToString(); }

            PictureTrain.ImageUrl = PictureTrainLabel.Text;


        }
        con.Close();
    }
```